# How to convert an object to a wrapper object in Ninject & C#?

Tags: c#, ninject, wrapper

I have wrapper classes for some 3rd party classes without interfaces, and I need to reference it in a fairly SOLID block of C# code.

At present, I have a static function to convert the instance into a wrapper instance.

Example Code.

```
class A
{
    public string Name;
}

interface IAWrapper
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

class AWrapper : IAWrapper
{
    private A Instance;
    public AWrapper(A instance)
    {
        Instance = instance;
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return Instance.Name;
        }
        set
        {
            Instance.Name = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I want a function like

```
var a = new A() {Name = "bob"};
var wrapped = kernel.wrap<IAWrapper>(a);
```

Where `wrapped` will be an instance of `AWrapper`, and it was passed `a` for `Instance`

Does Ninject possess a way to do this?  To request a wrapper class interface, the instance to be wrapped, and get back the wrapped class?

(my apologies, I'm sure there are much more clear ways to ask this, but if I knew how to ask it better, I might know the answer as well.  :)  )

Comment: You don't need Ninject for this. You can simply call `new AWrapper(new A { Name = "bob" })`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the kernel was already bound you can use `ConstructorArgument` to specify constructor arguments. The name of the constructor parameter is the first argument of the class.

```
var a = new A() { Name = "bob" };
var instance = new Ninject.Parameters.ConstructorArgument("instance", a);
var wrapper = kernel.Get<IAWrapper>(instance);
```

Where `wrapped` will be an instance of `AWrapper`, and it was passed `a` for `instance` parameter in the constructor.